# Assembly IA32 $16, %esp

Tags: assembly

I have just started learning Assembly. I am keep writing simple C coding and compiling it to assembly. The following is the very simple one.

C coding

```
int main(){
    int a;
    a = 25;
    return a;
}
```

Assembly

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $25, -4(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret
```

What I don't understand is that why does 16 is substracted from %esp.

Comment: I think this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Data_manipulation_instructions) has a piece about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [meaning of add esp, -10 in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627007/meaning-of-add-esp-10-in-assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates some space on the stack (called function stack frame) to store local variables, and will get destroyed as soon as you leave the function. The number generate by the compiler can vary and more than what function needs.

Answer (score 5):

**That allocates 16 bytes on the stack.** On the x86 architecture, the stack goes from higher addresses to lower addresses.  Subtracting 16 from the stack pointer allocates that memory for your function's use.